# useState hook setter incorrectly overwrites state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Here's the issue: I'm trying to call 2 functions on a button click. Both functions update the state (I'm using the useState hook). First function updates value1 correctly to 'new 1', but after 1s (setTimeout) second function fires, and it changes value 2 to 'new 2' BUT! It set's value1 back to '1'. Why is this happening?
Thanks in advance!

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const Test = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    value1: "1",
    value2: "2"
  });

  const changeValue1 = () => {
    setState({ ...state, value1: "new 1" });
  };
  const changeValue2 = () => {
    setState({ ...state, value2: "new 2" });
  };

  return (
    <>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          changeValue1();
          setTimeout(changeValue2, 1000);
        }}
      >
        CHANGE BOTH
      </button>
      <h1>{state.value1}</h1>
      <h1>{state.value2}</h1>
    </>
  );
};

export default Test;
```

Comment: could you log state at the start of `changeValue2`?

Comment: I highly recommend that you either split the object into two separate calls to `useState` or instead use `useReducer`.

Comment: Yes - second this. Just use two calls to useState()

Comment: `const [state, ...]`, and then referring to it in the setter... It will use the same state all the time.

Comment: Best course of action: use 2 separate `useState` calls, one for each "variable".

Answer (score 58, accepted):

**Welcome to the closure hell**. This issue happens because whenever `setState` is called, `state` gets a new memory reference, but the functions `changeValue1` and `changeValue2`, because of closure, keep the old initial `state` reference.

**A solution** to ensure the `setState` from `changeValue1` and `changeValue2` gets the latest state is by using a [callback](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate) (having the previous state as a parameter):

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";

const Test = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    value1: "1",
    value2: "2"
  });

  const changeValue1 = () => {
    setState((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, value1: "new 1" }));
  };
  const changeValue2 = () => {
    setState((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, value2: "new 2" }));
  };

  // ...
};
```

You can find a broader discussion about this closure issue [here](https://medium.com/@divyabiyani26/react-hooks-with-closures-usestate-v-s-usereducer-9e0c20e81051) and [here](https://dev.to/anpos231/react-hooks-the-closure-hell-71m).

Comment: A callback with useState hook seems to be an [undocumented](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) feature, are you sure that works?

Comment: @HMR Yes, it works and it's documented on another page. Take a look at the "Functional updates" section here: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html ("If the new state is computed using the previous state, you can pass a function to setState")

Comment: @HMR But, to be honest, they could have done a better job in making this more visible.

Comment: @AlbertoTrindadeTavares Yes, I was looking at the docs aswell, couldnt find anything. Thanks a lot for the answer!

Comment: @Bartek Glad to help :)

Comment: Your first solution isn't just an "easy solution", it's the correct method. The second one would only work if the component is designed as a singleton, and even then i'm not sure about that because state becomes a new object each time.

Comment: @Scimonster You're right. It only works if the component is used as a singleton (and it works properly in this case; I have tested). I will remove it from my answer to avoid misleading other people who come to this page. Thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 21):

Your functions should be like this:

```
const changeValue1 = () => {
    setState((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, value1: "new 1" }));
};
const changeValue2 = () => {
    setState((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, value2: "new 2" }));
};
```

Thus you make sure you are not missing any existing property in the current state by using the previous state when the action is fired. Also thus you avoid to have to manage closures.

Answer (score 6):

When `changeValue2` is invoked, initial state is held so the state turns back to the inital state and then `value2` property is written.

Next time `changeValue2` is invoked after that, it holds the state `{value1: "1", value2: "new 2"}`, so `value1` property is overwritten.

You need an arrow function for the `setState` parameter.

```js
const Test = () => {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState({
    value1: "1",
    value2: "2"
  });

  const changeValue1 = () => {
    setState(prev => ({ ...prev, value1: "new 1" }));
  };
  const changeValue2 = () => {
    setState(prev => ({ ...prev, value2: "new 2" }));
  };

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          changeValue1();
          setTimeout(changeValue2, 1000);
        }}
      >
        CHANGE BOTH
      </button>
      <h1>{state.value1}</h1>
      <h1>{state.value2}</h1>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<Test />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

What's happening is that both `changeValue1` and `changeValue2` see the state **from the render they were created in**, so when your component render for the first time these 2 functions see:

```
state= {
  value1: "1",
  value2: "2"
}
```

When you click on the button, `changeValue1` is called first and changes the state to `{value1: "new1", value2: "2"}` as expected.

Now, after 1 second, `changeValue2` is called, but this function still see the initial state (`{value1; "1", value2: "2"}`), so when this function updates the state this way:

`setState({ ...state, value2: "new 2" });`

you end up seeing: `{value1; "1", value2: "new2"}`.

[source](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#why-am-i-seeing-stale-props-or-state-inside-my-function)