# Why the count value increment by 1 not by 2 with two setState in React

Tags: reactjs, react-native, use-state

Here's the code that does not work  :

```
import { useState } from "react";

const Counter = () => {

const [count,setCount]= useState(0);

const buttonHandler = ()=>{
    setCount(count+1);
    setCount(count+1);
}


return (

    <div >
        {count}
        <button onClick={buttonHandler}>+</button>
    </div>


);
```

}

I don't really get what is happening under the hood of React. I saw through some videos it would work if I did this:

```
const buttonHandler = ()=>{
    setCount(prevCount => prevCount+1);
    setCount(prevCount => prevCount+1);
}
```

But I don't feel like I really get why the first one is not working

Comment: You've created a closure over `count` so they both get passed the value of `count` at the time of the last render cycle. Pass a callback to avoid this `setCount(prevCount => prevCount+1);`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [useState hook setter incorrectly overwrites state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58193166/usestate-hook-setter-incorrectly-overwrites-state)

Comment: If I understand, the  `setCount(count +1)`  always refers to the first value of `count` declared in `useState` so thats why it does not work, right ?

Comment: It refers to the value of `count` at the time the function containing them is declared, which will be at the beginning of each render cycle. So your count will increment, but only by one. By passing a callback React passes the most current state value to the callback avoiding a race condition

Answer (score 0):

In your function, buttonHandler, setCount isn't changing the value of count immediately. It's just updating the state that is used to set count the next time Counter is rendered.

So if count is 0, calling setCount with a value of count + 1 twice actually results in two calls to setCount with a value of 1.