# Why is this react code not incrementing by 2 but the second code that uses previous state is incrementing?

Tags: reactjs, react-state

I have 2 react codes, my goal is to increment count by 2 every time the method is called.
First code is incrementing by having count+1 and the second code is incrementing using prevState+1.

Can someone deeply explain why is second code incrementing by 2 but the first one is not ?

First code is implemented like this

`const [count,setCount]=useState(0)`

```
 const handleIncrement = ()=>{
    setCount(count+1);
    setCount(count+1);
  }
```

The second code

```
const handleIncrement = ()=>{
   setCount((prevState)=>prevState+1);
   setCount((prevState)=>prevState+1);
  }
```

Comment: Short answer: `count` is a const. So if `count` is 1 in the first example you're doing `setCount(1+1); setCount(1+1);`. `count` won't be updated to its new value until the next render.

Comment: This may help you.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69059320/why-the-count-value-increment-by-1-not-by-2-with-two-setstate-in-react

Comment: If count is 1 when I call setCount(1+1), how prevState is not 1 as well ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The confusion around this code relates to a couple really important things to know about React.

##### 1. State updates are asynchronous

Once you call a state setter function, React tracks the new value it should use for state but the function continues to execute with state unchanged.

State updates can be batched, meaning if you update state multiple times during a render cycle, React can optimize by only update state once at the end.

Using the updater function for setting state (`(prevState) => ...`) is the tool we can use to make multiple updates without just overwriting all but the last value. The `prevState` argument is not a `const`, but a function argument that can React will give us. It is guaranteed to hold the value of the latest setState call.

*Note: when we say state updates are async, this does not mean you can await them to get the updated value*

##### 2. `const`s cannot be reassigned or it will throw an error

This is the red flag that most people miss, and I think it'd due to the "magic" of react hooks making us believe that the rules of JavaScript have changed.

State is usually defined (and should be) as a `const`. That state value will never be reassigned and if you (or React) tried to it would throw an error.

I think this reminder helps us understand the function component lifecycle a little better. When a component re-renders, the function that defines the component is called again; and just like any other function in JavaScript, a new call to a function means all variables inside that function are completely separate from their values in previous function calls.

This is still how function components work, and why `useState` is so incredibly helpful.

`useState` allows us to track values that we want to persist across function calls to our component. It's still a brand new `const`, but it gets set to the correct previous or new value we set in state.

With this knowledge, it's easier to remember that state will not and can not ever be updated during a render.