# multiple react useState calls gives undefined property

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-hooks

I'm trying to implement a notes app with a `title` property. I, previously, had the notes app working w/o adding-a-title functionality but now that I've integrated it, I have the following issue: the return of the `textarea` element (the note text itself) is undefined while the return of the `input` element (the note title) returns the valid title.

The code below is, I'm certain, the component where the error stems from - the component being `AddNote`.

What I've tried thus far:

- Using a callback, [in reference to closure hell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58193373)
- [Combining the states](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53575023/17365326)
- Tracing the error with React Dev Tools on Chrome

What I haven't tried:

- [Using `useReducer`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56533146/17365326)

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const AddNote = ({ handleAddNote }) => {
  const [noteTitle, setNoteTitle] = useState('');
  const [noteText, setNoteText] = useState('');

  const handleSaveClick = () => {
    if ((noteText.trim().length > 0) && (noteTitle.trim().length > 0)) {
      handleAddNote(noteText);
      setNoteText('');

      handleAddNote(noteTitle);
      setNoteTitle('');
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className='note new'>
      <div className="toolbar">
        <button
          className='add-delete-icon'
          onClick={handleSaveClick}
        >+</button>
        <input
          type="text"
          className="note-title"
          placeholder="Add a title..."
          value={noteTitle}
          onChange={
            event => setNoteTitle(event.target.value)
          }
          autoFocus
        />
      </div>
      <textarea
        className="note-text"
        placeholder="Add an idea..."
        value={noteText}
        onChange={
          event => setNoteText(event.target.value)
        }
      ></textarea>
    </div>
  );
};

export default AddNote;
```

Am I doing something incorrectly here, particularly with using multiple instances of `useState`, i.e., this idea of "batching" the 'setState' calls? Or rather, does the issue fall within the `handleSaveClick` anonymous function?

The dependent components - meaning, the one's that refer to adding-a-title-functionality - are the `Note` component ([Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/5CirkFEn)), the `NoteList` component ([Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/G9Tk8tNz)), and notable the `Home` component ([Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/GGJXvfpq)).

Comment: The code you're providing here seems to work - that is `handleAddNote` gets both values for the note text and title. When you say _"the return of the textarea element (the note text itself) is undefined"_, where are you checking the note text that makes you say it's `undefined`?

Comment: Weird to call handleAddNote with both the title and the text. How do you differentiate between them in the callback?

Comment: Have you tried to consolelog before call setNoteText? Is it undefined there? When is it undefined? Please, show us all relevant code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your updates, you've shown that you've defined the following function in your `Home` component:

```js
const addNote = (title, text) => {
  const date = new Date();
  const options = { ... };

  const newNote = {
    id: nanoid(),
    title: title, // <--- here
    text: text, // <--- here
    date: date.toLocaleDateString(undefined, options)
  };

  const newNotes = [...notes, newNote];
  setNotes(newNotes);
};
```

This `addNote()` function expects two arguments to be passed to it, a `title` and `text` which is then used in your `newNote` object (see `<--- here` comments above). You're then passing this `addNote` function as a prop to `NoteList`:

```
<NotesList
  notes={notes}
  handleAddNote={addNote}
  handleDeleteNote={deleteNote}
/>
```

And then again, inside of `NoteList`, you're passing `handleAddNote` (which is a reference to your `addNote` function) to `AddNote`:

```js
<AddNote handleAddNote={handleAddNote} />
```

As a result, when you call `handleAddNote()` inside of your `AddNote` component, you're calling the `addNote()` function defined in `Home`, which needs to be passed both your `title` and `text` in the one call like so:

```js
const handleSaveClick = () => {
  if ((noteText.trim().length > 0) && (noteTitle.trim().length > 0)) {
    handleAddNote(noteTitle, noteText);
    setNoteText('');
    setNoteTitle('');
  }
};
```

Comment: @duke no worries. Yes, that's right,  the order of the arguments that you call `handleAddNote()` must align/match up with the order of the parameters of the function definition, so for `(title, text) => `, the value you want to be used for `title` is passed to `hanldeAddNote()` first and then the value for `text`)

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the [code](https://pastebin.com/GGJXvfpq), you should call `handleAddNote` like this

```
if ((noteText.trim().length > 0) && (noteTitle.trim().length > 0)) {
    handleAddNote(noteTitle, noteText);
    setNoteText('');
    setNoteTitle('');
  }
```

`handleAddNote` is addNote func in `Home.jsx`. `addNote` take `title` and `text` as arguments

```
const addNote = (title, text) => {....}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say that the problem is here:

```
const handleSaveClick = () => {
  if ((noteText.trim().length > 0) && (noteTitle.trim().length > 0)) {
    handleAddNote(noteText);
    setNoteText('');

    handleAddNote(noteTitle);
    setNoteTitle('');
  }
};
```

You're calling `handleAddNote()` twice. What does this function look like?